# Find the $n$th term of the series, where the sum of the first n terms of the series is $(4n + 5)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The sum of the first $n$ terms of the series is $(4n + 5)^2$. Find the $n$th term of the series.

So far I have got $n_2=88, n_3=120, n_4=152, n_5=184  ...$

How should I continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms and $t_n$ is the $n$th term, then observe that:
$$
S_{n} - S_{n-1} = t_n
$$

Comment: Sorry, can you give me another hint please? I still don't get it.

Comment: Whoops made a typo. Anyways, what my hint is trying to say is: "To find the sum of the first $n$ terms, all I need to do is find the sum of the first $(n-1)$ terms, then add the $n$th term." Note that to find $S_{n-1}$, simply replace $n$ with $n-1$ to obtain:
$$
S_{n-1} = (4(n-1)+5)^2
$$